# Mac M1 Brew install kong

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon

I'm using the new M1 MacBook Pro.

I've managed to install homebrew, but the Kong install through homebrew uses the old file location (same as the Intel chips) and not the new location for homebrew.

To access it in homebrew, use:

```
brew tap kong/kong
brew install kong
```

I'm following their tutorial here: https://docs.konghq.com/install/macos/?_ga=2.236595011.392185721.1624934508-1076638900.1622674895

Seems to get stuck on installing https://luarocks.org/kong-lapis-1.8.3.1-1.src.rock

Has anyone been able to successfully install Kong using homebrew?

Comment: `brew install kong` says the formula doesn't exist

Comment: @unbeatable101 have updated question

Comment: It gets stuck for me too, but it seems to be installing it to `/opt/homebrew`, as it should

Answer (score -1):

Only option seems to be install Docker version on M1.